# Extract hex strings from binary file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary-data, data-extraction

for the binary file I want to extract the hex strings in green (date and hour) and in blue. The hex string in blue is between the byte 09 and 00.

I've been able to extract using regex the date and hour and partially the hex string in blue. For this I've set as "line separator" the byte 09 (\x09)

The issue I have maybe could be fix with a regex to get the string between 09 and 00, but currently with my regex (^20.*) I'm getting undesired 
and non ascii bytes. May someone help me to get bytes only between 09 and 00.

My current code:

```
BEGIN{  $/="\x09".force_encoding("BINARY")   }

IO.foreach("file.dat"){ |l|

    line = l.unpack('H*')[0]
    next unless line =~ /(.{8}2d.{4}2d.{4})20(.{4}3a.{4}3a.{4})|(^20.*)/

        if ( $1 != nil and $2 != nil )
            date = $1
            hour = $2
            p date.gsub(/../) { |b| b.hex.chr }
            p hour.gsub(/../) { |b| b.hex.chr } 
        end

        if $3 != nil            
            p $3.gsub(/20/,"").gsub(/../) { |b| b.hex.chr }         
        end 
}
```

Current output

```
"2017-10-19"
"15:43:27"
"83492624790981030E100000\x00\x18\v\x16\x84\x13\x05$B#q\x000\x03\x81\x01\n\x00\x00v\x00\x0000000003\t"
"2017-12-05"
"09:32:15"
"001104059419632801001B237100300381010A0000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xD0\x00\x00\x00\b\xFEF\xCC\x00\x06\xE7\f\x13\x0F+\e\xB5\xE1/\x00\xB5\x83I&$y\t"
=> nil
```

Expected output

```
"2017-10-19"
"15:43:27"
"83492624790981030E100000"
"2017-12-05"
"09:32:15"
"001104059419632801001B237100300381010A0000"
=> nil
```

The file looks like this:
[image]

Attached sample file:
[file.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4aq0gzw5ykm1jcm/file.dat?dl=0)

Comment: Try something like: `s.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join`

Comment: Hi Aaditya, I've tested like this but doesn't work, print is wrong for $3 `p $3.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the bytes starting with `20` and ending with `00` you need to change the regex like this:

```
next unless line =~ /(.{8}2d.{4}2d.{4})20(.{4}3a.{4}3a.{4})|^20(.*?0?)0{2}/
```

Basically I changed only the last part of the regex from `(^20.*)` to `^20(.*?0?)0{2}`.
Here's the explanation:

- starting from 20 - `^20`
- match as little as possible - `.*?`
- until you get to two consecutive 0s `0{2}`
- the `0?` after `.*?` handles the case where you have `X0 00`

Also I'm not including `20` in the captured group since you are removing it later in the code anyways, so you can remove the `.gsub(/20/, '')` in

```
p $3.gsub(/20/,"").gsub(/../) { |b| b.hex.chr }
```

Comment: Excellent Viktor, I knew that modifying the second regex was the way to fix it, but I didn´t know how to build the correct regex. Thanks so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

IN_FNAME = "file.dat"
OUT_FNAME = "out_file.dat"
END_OF_LINE = "\x09"

str_out = ''
File.foreach(IN_FNAME, sep=END_OF_LINE) do |line|
  dt_str = line[3..21]
  if (DateTime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') rescue nil)
    puts dt_str.split(' ')
    next
  end
  arr = line.unpack("C*")
  next unless arr.first == 32
  a = arr.map(&:chr).select { |c| c.match? /\d/ }
  puts a.join
  str_out << a.map(&:ord).pack("C*")    
end
2017-10-19
15:43:27
83492624790981030100000000000003
2017-12-05
09:32:15
0011040594196328010012371003003810100000
```

The final step is to write the binary file `OUT_FNAME`.

```
File.binwrite(OUT_FNAME, str_out)
  #=> 72
```

As seen, 72 bytes are written. Here is a screenshot of that file when viewed with a hex editor.

[image]

This can be compared with the screenshot shown in the question.

We can read that file to confirm that it was written correctly.

```
File.binread(OUT_FNAME)
  #=> "834926247909810301000000000000030011040594196328010012371003003810100000"
```

See [DateTime::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-unpack).

Note that to print the date and time both must be valid. For example, `"0000-19-39 29:00:00"`, which would be accepted by a simple regular expression, would be skipped.

Comment: Hi Cary. Thanks for your solution. My final step is to write the extracted hex strings to a binary file. How can I include something like `byte.to_i(16). pack('C*')` in your command `arr.map(&:chr).select....` ?

Comment: I was able to get this code but I'm not sure if could be shorter `str=arr.map(&:chr).select { |c| c.match /\d/}.each_slice(2).map{|z| z.join}.map{|b| b.to_i(16)}.pack("C*")` and after this `IO.binwrite("testfile", str) `

Comment: Ger, I've not had a lot of experience with binary files, so it would better if a reader with greater knowledge of `pack/unpack` and reading/writing binary files would respond to your question, preferably by giving an answer that addresses your complete question, as opposed to responding to your comment above only. Perhaps @Stefan would be kind enough to do that.

Comment: Thanks anyway Cary for your help and honesty. I mix my original code with your solution since I read as binary and you read in a more direct and fast way I think.

Comment: Hi Cary, thanks for continue helping me. It looks pretty compact your solution, the only thing is that I need that the values reflected in output file be these:

    `83 49 26 24 79 09 81 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
    00 11 04 05 94 19 63 28 01 00 12 37 10 03 00 38 10 10 00 00`
 
so, for each array "a" captured from input file I need to do like this
`str_out << a.join.scan(/../).map { |b| b.to_i(16) }.pack('C*') << END_OF_LINE`

It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm doing extra steps in this part or is fine for you. Thanks again.

Comment: Ger, I'll have another look in the morning.